# Ionic popup is force closed after app permission window closes

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, permissions, popup

I have two apps, App1 and App2.  App1 is passing information to App2 and its working.  However I have encountered an odd issue on Android only.

If the user has installed App2, but never initialized it, its causing a Popup issue in App2.  Specifically, the App1 launches and passes info to App2, but App2 is in the process of inializing the first time which asks for permissions.  In the background, I can see the App2 popup (which acknowledges the data passed from App1) - but in the foreground are the App2 permissions windows (Location/GPS, etc).  When the user selects the permission level (deny/accept, etc - it doesn't matter which one) it closes BOTH the permission window AND the custom Popup.

How can I prevent the Popup from being closed automatically?  I tried moving the popup close button to the top of the popup - I was thinking the Permission window click was also passing through to the popup window which was possibly hitting the popup "close" button - but thats not the case.  Even I remove the close button, the Popup still closes when the permission window closes.

How can I keep the popup window to persist when the app permission windows are closed?

Comment: you have to handle it inside `this.androidPermissions.checkPermission` if user accept or deny handle your custom popup inside this permission handler.
Read this Article: https://medium.com/@rajsm139/location-permissions-and-accuracy-ionic-4-cdc9729485b5

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib - to clarify, its just a regular popup that happens to popup during the app initialization.  Its also a the same popup that would occur regularly throughout the app.  Its just the first init, the popup gets stuck behind the App Permission windows....and somehow also is force closed (not even a console.log is triggered) when the app permission window closes.